# Change default temp directory for PHP file uploads

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm making a website locally that allows the upload of .pdf files, when these are uploaded locally they go to `C:\xampp\tmp` but when I host the site on my University server I don't have access to the temporary directory, is there any way I can change the default temporary location for the file?

Thanks in advance,
Dave.

Comment: [`upload_tmp_dir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir), but normal hosters will have a writable tmp dir already set up for you.

Comment: Nice one, good man cheers!

Comment: ini_set('upload_tmp_dir', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\OR\tmp');
echo ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');

  how come when i do this, the location is still the original?

Comment: Because you cannot set it in code. it's [`PHP_INI_SYSTEM`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php), so in `php.ini` or webserver-config _only_.

Comment: Aw crap, then I'm back to square one then lol!

Comment: Well, as I said, it's probably fine. You most likely don't even have to know where that temp dir is, just take `tmp_name`, and if you plan to keep the file for longer, move it to a directory within your project.

Answer (score 2):

The location where uploaded files land can be configured using the [upload_tmp_dir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) configuration option.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
putenv('TMPDIR=/path/to/dir');
```

than you can check your tmp directory

```
sys_get_temp_dir()
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that you had no right of access to the `temp` directory. In `temp` directory are stored session data.

You should check temp direcory using:

```
sys_get_temp_dir()
```

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(reports/DavidC_Introduction_to_EHT.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Will take a look at the function you posted