# php set temp directory

Tags: php, temp

Is it possible to change the value that the function sys_get_temp_dir() returns?

My problem is that I don't have write permissions to that directory ( /tmp ) and I can't change that.

Thanks

Comment: Then just use another directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default temp directory for PHP file uploads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692705/change-default-temp-directory-for-php-file-uploads)

Comment: Or you can change the path from `sys_temp_dir` in your ini file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an environmental variable:

```
<?php
putenv('TMPDIR=/foo/bar');
echo sys_get_temp_dir(); // Outputs: /foo/bar
```

Comment: However, I'm getting some unexpected quirks under mod php. (Php 5.4).

Comment: Unfortunately when SAFE MODE is turned on I can't .

Comment: I get an error:Warning: putenv(): Safe Mode warning: Cannot set environment variable 'TMPDIR' - it's not in the allowed list 

The real issue is that when I try to use 'code'ZipArchive::open("php://output", ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE)'code'  I get an error:
    ZipArchive::open(): Unable to access php://output in ... 
and I assumed that is because I have no write privileges in /tmp.
I don't know

Comment: Can you use .htaccess?  Try setting TMPDIR using SetEnv there.  (>= Php 5.5).

Comment: Thanks. I found a solution to my problem by specifying a file name in one of the directories I can write and then echoing the contents of the generated file